# Is Ubuntu natty likely to get newer versions of Ruby?

Tags: ubuntu, ruby

The current version of Ruby in natty is 1.9.2 p0. The current version is p290, which is the second release after p0. So if Ruby used normal versioning it would be 1.9.2.3 (or really, 2.2.3, but let's not get into that).

Anyway -- is it likely that later ruby releases will make their way into natty?

Answer (score 1):

The ruby package in ubuntu depends on the debian one. And usually it's not the last one.

You can search for the rubys PPAs in launchpad and see if someone has packaged the last versions

Comment: thanks! questions: 1. what's the relevant debian thing to check? does each ubuntu release use what's in debian unstable? 2) how do i search for ruby PPAs?

Comment: 1) if the package name doesn't contain the "ubuntu" string in it, then they just use the same package that is in debian unstable. If you see the "ubuntu" string is because it has ubuntu's developer hacks (minor or major) on it. 2) just google "ruby ppa site:launchpad.net" however I've done a search and seems that there used to be ppas for ruby but that all of them are discontinued. If you have time to cooperate you can port the last version of ruby to a deb package and upload as your own PPA to benefit other users :-)

Comment: hmmm, search for "ruby1.9 ppa site:launchpad.net" and you'll get more results. A ppa is a personal package so use it with caution

Comment: debian testing has p180, unstable has p290 -- is there any principle/pattern that would suggest if either of them make it into natty, or if they will go into the next ubuntu only?

Comment: As I said: Version will not change officially. You can have unofficial ones via PPA as this answer explains. Unofficial packages may be in any version (soon).

Comment: Normally they doesn't modify the version of a package during a release cycle. In that time is likely that upgrades are just for security or stability issues. Another concept is the term backport. If the maintainer (or group) think that is worth to update the version of a package they do it in the backport repository <http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty-backports/>. Users can request backport updates at launchpad <https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu> but the decision is for the package maintainer; and in this case there isn't one for ubuntu, you'll need to contact the debian one...

Comment: ... also you can ask him how to backport it and do his job under his supervision. That will increase the chances that he uploads your work (after a revision) to the main repos (through backports) benefiting the rest of the comuninty; also is common to backport the version from the next release to the current one.

Comment: Brightbox have a PPA for 1.9.3 http://wiki.brightbox.co.uk/docs:ruby-ng

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, the version of Ruby in natty is 1.8 (1.8.7.302-2). See http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/ruby1.8

The same goes for Debian. http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=ruby

There is likely no way that the maintainers do a major (or minor) update in their current versions. All you get from Debian or Canonical are security fixes for the current version which do not change the version number.

Comment: there's a 1.8 and 1.9 package :-D http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/ruby1.9.1

Comment: Ok. Thank you. But it is in "universe", so not officially supported.

Comment: ahhh, okay, didn't realize